# Can't make the shortcut show up in start menu search results

Tags: windows-10

I have a shortcut that launches powershell and executes a script. I want it added to Start Menu so that when I press Win-key and type in 'My-shortcut' file name - it is displayed in search results. I tried adding it to both my user and system `\Start Menu\Programs` folders in `appData` and `Program Data` respectively with the same result - the shortcut is added to `All Apps` subfolder but search by name does not display it. Adding it to either `\Start Menu\` folder doesn't seem to help either. The thing is my Win10 office PC has same shortcut in `Program Data Start Menu\Programs` and search shows it just fine so it is some weird configuration difference.

Comment: The search feature uses Windows' indexed search engine. I might suggest waiting a while for the Index to be updated and then try searching again. Also ensure that the Windows Search Service is running.

Comment: @Dai It is there in the indexed folders. The thing is when I type "Chrome" into search it shows the `Google Chrome` shortcut. When I click open file location it opens the `Start Menu\Programs` folder. Other shortcuts from the same folder like say `Print Dialog` are not displayed when being searched for though. It looks like file type or attribute association or something.